# Remove all the [base]

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

[base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/base) (500-, 2 followers) needs some cleaning. Some uses need renaming (e.g. to [base-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/base-class)), and some uses just need to be deleted. I see there is also a C# keyword that needs to be taken care of.

Comment: But aren't all of it belong to us?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi you have no chance to survive make your time.

Comment: Snap!  Beat me to it.  It's the first thing I though of when screen turn on

Comment: Has anyone gotten around to dropping the base?

Answer (score 3):

The cases where the tag is used for numeric bases should be replaced with [radix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radix) (or [numeric-base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numeric-base)).